# how do i do something every second after Collision

Tags: c#, time, collision-detection, unity-game-engine

I am currently working on a football  game(American) and im working on a tackle mechanic. Now just having 2 things bumping into each-other did not work because the character would continue to move after being forced sideways on the ground. To make the character stop after making contact with the other rigid body, I thought the best way would be to use `Time.Timescale = 0;` . However the problem with this is the fact that the 2 rigid body's then just go through each-other.to solve this I think the best way would be to set time scale to 0 after 1 second of collision. How can I do this?

Feedback is always appreciated **;)**

Comment: is your main problem that the rigid bodies continue to move after you have determined you would like them to stop?

Answer (score 1):

to invoke a method delayed within unity presuming it is a monobehaviour.

the Invoke method apears to be what you are after
http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.Invoke.html

however please be aware that `Time.Timescale` effects everything and is not local and would more than likely not get the effect you are after. setting the Velocity of the gameObject to zero should get the desired outcome.

```
var rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
rb.velocity = Vector3.zero;
```

Answer (score 1):

Time.Timescale would effect your whole game.

Actually Time.Timsescale is

- **The scale at which the time is passing. This can be used for slow motion effects.**
- **When timeScale is 1.0 the time is passing as fast as realtime. When timeScale is 0.5 the time is passing 2x slower than realtime.**
- **When timeScale is set to zero the game is basically paused if all your functions are frame rate independent.**

From [Unity Documentation](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Time-timeScale.html)

Well, what you can do is,

In script attached to `Rigidbody's` GameObject you can implement `OnCollisionEnter`.

```
Rigidbody _rb;

void Start()
{
    _rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
}

void OnCollisionEnter(Collision col){
    _rb.velocity = Vector3.zero;
}
```

It will stop your player even after collision with ground. :)

So you can further modify collision condition like if body strikes to some specific object, you can detect it by `tag` or some other properties.

```
void OnCollisionEnter(Collision col){
    if (col.gameObject.tag == "TAG_OF_SPECIFIC_OBJECT")
        _rb.velocity = Vector3.zero;
}
```